# TypeORM throws an error after insert with the queryBuilder in Nest.js

Tags: express, nestjs, typeorm, node-mysql, node-mysql2

I have an entity and service defined as follows.

1. `user.entity.js`

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
  @Column({
    type: 'binary',
    length: 16,
    select: false,
    primary: true,
    default: () => `(UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), 1))`,
  })

  id: string;
  @Index()
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 225, nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 15, unique: true, nullable: false })
  MSISDN: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 225, unique: true, nullable: false })
  email_address: string;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  created_at: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime', nullable: true, onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

2. `user.service.js`

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  create(user: DeepPartial<User>): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .values({ ...user})
      .execute();
  }
}
```

Whenever I attempt to create a user from the Postman client, the record is in fact inserted into the database but I get a 500 response from the postman client.

Postman response

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

The CLI error looks like this:

```
[Nest] 9084   - 15/03/2021, 11:17:47   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity. +331142ms
Error: Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.
    at C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\ReturningResultsEntityUpdator.js:128:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ReturningResultsEntityUpdator.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\ReturningResultsEntityUpdator.js:122:46)
    at step (C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:122:57)
    at C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:115:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:111:16)
    at ReturningResultsEntityUpdator.insert (C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\ReturningResultsEntityUpdator.js:87:24)
    at InsertQueryBuilder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mnengwa\workspace\kodisha\kodisha-web-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\InsertQueryBuilder.js:105:76)
```

Comment: I get the same error, did you find a solution to this issue ?

Comment: Any updates? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had to specify the `reload` option as `false` in my `save` call (not `insert`) to make the error go away.

For `insert` you want to add an `updateEntity(false)` call to your chain before calling `execute`.

There's more context here:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4651

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `id` attribute for the `User` entity as follows -

```
@PrimaryColumn()
@Generated('uuid')
id: string;
```